# Add something into L.CircleMarker

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapping, icon

I have two different colored CircleMarkers for two geojson layer. Is it possible to add a letter into those circles, without using divIcon?

This is where I give them the color.

```
function getColor(iconcategory) {
        return iconcategory == 'tram' ? 'black' :
            iconcategory == 'ubahn' ? 'purple' :
                'red';
    }
```

This is the popup.

```
        function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        var popupContent = "<b>" +
            feature.properties.name + "</b>" ;

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    };
```

This is the rest.

```
onEachFeature: forEachFeature,
                    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                            radius: 10,
                            opacity: .9,                            
                            color: getColor(feature.properties.iconcategory),
                            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.iconcategory),
                            fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        //  html: feature.properties.iconcategory[0].toUpperCase(),
                        })
                            .bindTooltip(feature.properties.name);
```

The html tag from the divIcon isn't working. Is there any chance that I don't have to use the divIcon
And... is there any possibility to add a second circle to the circle or do I have to do this with a divIcon as well? I use the circlemarker, because it's easy and doesn't require a lot of code.

Comment: The answer is gonna be "no": in Leaflet, a `CircleMarker` is ultimately a draw call to a `<canvas>` or a SVG element for circle, and there's no text support for those. You have another alternative, which is to create a `DivIcon` and give it rounded borders via CSS.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thank you, I feared it.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is based on @IvanSanchez idea of using `L.divIcon` for text and draw circle around it via CSS style.

The main factor to make it successful is to set icon width and height to twice the circle radius plus twice the circle border width, otherwise circle will become ellipse instead.

To make solution flexible, there is base CSS class `circle` for creating circle and then subclasses `circle1` and `circle2` for individual styling (could be more of course). Desired marker is then created via function, where circle radius, circle border width and circle CSS subclass are input parameters.

So, it this are the CSS classes for circle and text styling:

```
  .circle {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .circle.circle1 {
    background: rgba(0, 57, 128, 0.2);
    border-color: #3388FF;
    color: white;
  }
  .circle.circle2 {
    background: rgba(0, 57, 128, 0.2);
    border-color: green;
    color: yellow;
  }
```

and this is marker creating function:

```
function circleWithText2(latLng, txt, radius, borderWidth, circleClass) {
  var size = radius * 2;
  var style = 'style="width: ' + size + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; border-width: ' + borderWidth + 'px;"';
  var iconSize = size + (borderWidth * 2);
  var icon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<span class="' + 'circle ' + circleClass + '" ' + style + '>' + txt + '</span>',
    className: '',
    iconSize: [iconSize, iconSize]
  });
  var marker = L.marker(latLng, {
    icon: icon
  });
  return(marker);
}
```

then with the following calls:

```
circleWithText2([44.6, 22.6], '67', 30, 3, 'circle1').addTo(map);
circleWithText2([44.6, 22.5], '89', 20, 2, 'circle2').addTo(map);
```

this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There actually exists Leaflet plugin [leaflet-labeled-circle](https://github.com/w8r/leaflet-labeled-circle) that does exactly what you want: circle marker with text inside, but it's rather complicated and I couldn't get ti working the way I wanted.

Simple solution to this is to create your own group marker, which is combination of `L.circleMarker` and `L.marker` with `L.divIcon` icon. This combination can be wrapped in a function that creates combined marker at desired location with desired properties.

Below is an example how this can be done. Marker creating function can be of course further parameterized for more flexibility in marker look and feel.

```
<style>
  .circle-with-txt {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .txt {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>
.
.
.
var map = L.map('map').setView([44.635, 22.653], 11);
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

function circleWithText(latLng, txt, circleOptions) {
  var icon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<div class="txt">' + txt + '</div>',
    className: 'circle-with-txt',
    iconSize: [40, 40]
  });
  var circle = L.circleMarker(latLng, circleOptions);
  var marker = L.marker(latLng, {
    icon: icon
  });
  var group = L.layerGroup([circle, marker]);
  return(group);
}

circleWithText([44.64, 22.66], '123', {radius: 30}).addTo(map);
circleWithText([44.7, 22.7], '45', {radius: 20, weight: 2, color: 'green'}).addTo(map);
```

This is how the result of the above code looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I've solved it with a 'divIcon' and got a crooked circle. I'm a bloody beginner and will have to live with my "circle" for now.

Comment: See the other answer how to make circle round when using `L.divIcon` icon.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an easy solution for my case, and it looks kind of like your second suggestion @TomazicM. Just styled my marker completely in CSS.

```
  .leaflet-marker-icon {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 30px;
        border-width: 3px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .ubahn.leaflet-marker-icon {
        background: #f66
    }

    .tram.leaflet-marker-icon {
        background: #f6f
    }
```

And then used the `divIcon` for my marker. And the properties inside are working as well. This was my main focus.

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: L.divIcon({
                        className: feature.properties.iconcategory,
                        html: feature.properties.iconcategory[0].toUpperCase(),
                        iconSize: L.point(25, 25),
                    })
                })

                  .bindTooltip(feature.properties.name);
```

[image]